# How to serialize the following xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

I know how to serialize an xml. But this following example I have never done yet. And I can't figure out how to do it either.

```
 <Products>
   <row **id="10"**>
     <ProductName>Cola</ProductName>
     <Amount>3</Amount>
   </row>
   <row **id="20"**>
     <ProductName>Fanta</ProductName>
     <Amount>6</Amount>
   </row>
 </Products>
```

So I want use xml serialization, most of the xml is done, but this little part of it remains.

I can't manage to put the id behind the row. I bet I need to use xmlattribute but I don't really know how to implement.

Can someone please help me out on how to get the id in "Row"  element with xml serialization specifically.

(I did find some way to do it with another way, but since this XML is pretty large and most of it I finished so I would love to continue. And also don't want to go around any little problem.)

Comment: I think you're mixing buzzwords there. xml serialization is an END PRODUCT - storing the definition of something in an xml-based format. once it's in xml... it's just xml. you use XPath to find things and DOM operations to manipulate/exact things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create an ID member in your class and then mark it with the `XmlAttribute` attribute, for instance:

```
Public Class MyRow

    <XmlAttribute()> _
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _id As Integer


    Public Property ProductName() As String
        Get
            Return _productName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _productName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _productName As String


    Public Property Amount() As Integer
        Get
            Return _amount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _amount = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _amount As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot - didn't know it worked this way. What I find weird is that it doesn't have a seperate method to do this. It's like the XmlAttribute has almost everything you need.

Comment: How do I this exact same with my elements ?  I normally use properties to fill data into my xml.

Comment: You can apply `XmlAttribute` to any field or property.  I updated my example to use properties instead of fields.

Comment: Ye I figured out that bit, but lets say the element you are trying to add an xmlattribute to is NOT a class. Meaning the id="10" would be written in the "ProductName" element.

Comment: Oh, well, for that, I'd actually make a `ProductName` class.  If there's an easier way to do that, I'm not aware of it.